# Как вывести столько символов? postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица A с Transaction_id.

в столбце есть разные цифры от нуля до миллиарда.

```
1
2
...
11
..
100
101
...
123456
123457
...и т.д.
```

Вопрос как мне вывести поля где только 4 символа и 3-символ 7?
например так:

```sql
select Transaction_id from A where Transaction_id like '**7*'
```

этим запросом хотел дать понять мысли, сам запрос неправильный.

Comment: *в столбце есть разные цифры от нуля до миллиарда* Это называется "числа". *например так* Сперва желательно почитать [документацию](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE), а потом писать код - звезда для LIKE есть обычный символ, а не шаблон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте верный шаблон:

```sql
SELECT transaction_id
  FROM a
 WHERE CAST(transaction_id AS TEXT) LIKE '__7_'
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Student Не за что. Не забывайте отмечать выбранные ответы как верные, нажав на галочку слева. А то я вижу, что у вас ни один не отмечен.

Answer (score 1):

Если тип столбца *Transaction_id* символьный, то:

```
WHERE Transaction_id LIKE '__7_'
```

Если целочисленный, тогда:

```
WHERE Transaction_id BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 AND (Transaction_id / 10 % 10) = 7
```